# Query Builder and Conditional Statements

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, query-builder

```
$query = DB::select('thing')->from('things')->where('thing', '=', 'something');

if ($other_thing)
{
    $query->and_where('other_thing', '=', 'something else');
}

$query->order_by('thing', 'ASC')->limit(10)->execute()->as_array();

foreach ($query as $row)
{
    echo $row['thing'];
}
```

And what the problem is?

Well:

```
echo $row['thing'] -> nothing.
print_r($query) -> an object and not an array.
```

What am I doing wrong? Can someone help me on this? Please!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$result = $query->order_by('thing', 'ASC')->limit(10)->execute()->as_array();

foreach ($result as $row)
{
    echo $row['thing'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the above answer, the problem is that the execute function is actually returning an instance of [Database_Result](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Database_Result). As the above post points out you are able to call various functions on this object that will then return the data in various formats (see the previous link for a full list of available functions)

This provides various benefits - [this page](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/database/results) describes them all